# How do I fix "Failed to serialize user into session" when a user logs in? (node.js passport)

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am following a node.js passport tutorial (github: https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Nodejs-Passport-Login). Registering a user works fine but for some reason when I enter those credentials on the log in page, this occurs:

> Error: Failed to serialize user into session

All the solutions I've seen for this problem use code that I already have:

```js
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'}, 
    authenticateUser))
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) =>
        done(null, user.id))
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => 
        { return done(null, getUserById(id)) })
```

And in the server.js file:

```js
const initialisePassport = require('./passport-config')
const { required } = require('nodemon/lib/config')
initialisePassport(
    passport, 
    email => users.find(user => user.email === email),
    id => users.find(user => user.id === id)
)
```

Is there anything I'm missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I found the problem. I returned a boolean value of true and a message:

```js
if(user == null){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'No user found with that email'})

        }

        try{
            if(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)){
                return done(null, true, {message:'Password correct'})
            } else{
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Password incorrect'})
            }
```

That was not necessary and it was using a boolean value instead of a JSON object so I replaced it with passing a user in the return statement:

```js
if(user == null){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'No user found with that email'})

        }

        try{
            if(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)){
                return done(null, user)
            } else{
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Password incorrect'})
            }
```